# Не отображаются png файлы, ошибка с js,css файлами в проекте ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mvc, маршрутизация, png

Здравствуйте,
при запуске веб-приложения на ASP.NET MVC загружается главная страница Default.aspx, на ней не отображаются png картинки и возникает ошибка

> :33120/Views/Default?ReturnUrl=%2fScripts%2fjquery-3.1.0.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

и в адресной строке отображается

> localhost:33120/Views/Default?ReturnUrl=%2fViews%2fDefault.aspx

при этом номер строки в ошибке ссылается видимо на вот эту строку в Default.aspx (так как при перемещении этой строки, номер в ошибке соответственной ей изменяется.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Поискав подобные ошибки в интернете, нашла, что проблема можем быть связана с использованием System.Web.Routing. Приложение в общих чертах имеет такую структуру

- Views

  - Default.aspx
- Content

  - bootstrap.min.css
- Resources

  - Images

    - logo.png
- Scripts

  - jquery-3.1.0.js
- Global.asax.cs

Поэтому в метод RegisterRoutes класса Global.asax.cs добавила

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathInfo}", new { folder = "Scripts" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathInfo}", new { folder = "Content" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathInfo}", new { folder = "Resources" });
```

При вызове картинки в Default.aspx

```
<img class="img-responsive center-block"
src=" <% ResolveUrl("~/Resources/Images/logo.png");%>"
alt="Image is lost."/>
```

Но ничего не изменилось и не помогло.
Помогите разрешить данную проблему, пожалуйста.

P.S Содержимое default.aspx(без первой по умолчанию строки)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Project</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class=".container-fluid" style="background: linear-gradient(45deg, #EECFBA, #C5DDE8); width: 100%">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 81px">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-4">
            <!--Logo picture---->
            <img class="img-responsive center-block"
                 src=" <% ResolveUrl("~/Resources/Images/logo.png");%>"
                 alt="Image is lost."/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
            <p style="color: black; font-family: fantasy; font-size: 36px;">
                <strong>P</strong>r<strong style="color: gold">oject</strong>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
    <!--Login form-->
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 81px; padding-top: 36px;">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4" style="background: silver">
            <form id="Form1" role="form" runat="server">
                <!--User name -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="font-size: 20px; padding-top: 15px;">Username</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserEmail" runat="server"
                                 CssClass="form-control"/>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator_UserEmail" runat="server"
                                         OnServerValidate="CustomValidator_UserEmail_OnServerValidate"/>
                </div>
                <!--Password-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label style="font-size: 20px; padding-top: 15px;">Password</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserPass" runat="server"
                                 CssClass="form-control"
                                 TextMode="Password"/>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator_UserPass" runat="server"
                                         OnServerValidate="CustomValidator_UserPass_OnServerValidate"/>
                </div>
                <!--Remeber pass-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRememberPassword" runat="server"
                                          CssClass="checkbox"/>
                            Forget me?
                        </label>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hpForgetPass" runat="server"
                                       Text="Lost your password?"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Authentication failed-->
                <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 5px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMessageIncredential" runat="server"
                               ForeColor="red"/>
                </div>
                <!--Login button-->
                <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 5px">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server"
                                CssClass="btn btn-primary center-block"
                                OnClick="btnLogin_OnClick"
                                Text="Log On"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Часть кода из Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnLogin_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomValidator_UserEmail.Validate();
    CustomValidator_UserPass.Validate();
    if (!Page.IsValid)
    {
        return;
    }
    var login = ClientServiceFactoryClass.CompanyService.AuthenticateUser(UserEmail.Text, UserPass.Text);

    if (login != -1)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserEmail.Text, cbRememberPassword.Checked);
        Response.Redirect(login == 1
            ? Routes.HOME_PAGE_OF_ADMIN
            : Routes.PAGE_OF_COMPANY_SHORT);
    }
    else
    {
        lblMessageIncredential.Text = Dictionary.INVALID_LOGIN;
        UserEmail.Text = string.Empty;
        UserPass.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Где, например, `public const string HOME_PAGE_OF_ADMIN =@"HomeAdmin.aspx";`

> Содержимое метода RegisterRoutes

```
routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;
routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathInfo}", new { folder = "Scripts" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathInfo}", new { folder = "Content" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("{folder}/{*pathInfo}", new { folder = "Resources" }); 
routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();
```

При запросе *localhost:33120/* отображает в адресной строке `localhost:33120/Views/Default?ReturnUrl=%‌​2f` при *localhost:33120/Default* этот адрес и остается, но ошибки все равно происходят.

> содержимое web.config секции system.web и system.webServer

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
    </modules>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Views/Default" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43622/discussion-on-question-by-onlnas---png----js-css-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите аттрибут `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`

```xml
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />
</modules>
```

Он загоняет все запросы в asp.net, включая запросы к статическим файлам - и на них начинают применяться правила авторизации.

А лучше - уберите эту секцию целиком. Скорее всего вы зачем-то вписали `<remove name="UrlRoutingModule" />`, у вас перестали работать extensionless url-ы, и вы выгуглили костыль в виде runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true".

Уберите оба костыля - и все заработает.

---

И да, раз это ASP.NET MVC приложение - ваши ссылки должны вести на методы контроллера, например `/Default`. У вас в качестве страницы логина почему-то прописано сразу представление - `Views/Default`. Страница у вас хоть как-то отображается только потому, что вы удалили защиту от прямого доступа в Views/Web.config.

Если учесть, что при этом, что на представлении вы используете server-side контролы (`runat="server"`, `btnLogin_OnClick`) - у вас обычное Web Pages (не MVC) приложение, в котором у вас зачем-то прикручен роутинг и страницы сложены в папку `Views`. Попробуйте создать приложение ASP.NET MVC и посмотреть где в нем вписываются обработчики действий и где - отображение результата.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Ваше решение помогло,все отобразилось. P.S. правда url так и остался  `localhost:33120/Views/Default?ReturnUrl=%2fViews%2fDefault.aspx` , но я так поняла,что надо учесть Вашу вторую часть сообщения и переделать?